# How scikit-learn stores its train data in decision trees?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

I'm trying to understand how scikit stores its train data in decision tree. Till now I'm able to understand that it stores sorted matrix which stores sorted indices (sorted by features). After sorting finding the split in continuous data becomes easy. But i'm unable to understand how the data is stored for next iteration(I have read that it stores indices of individual samples eg. samples[start:end] but confused how this works for further iterations after finding the first split).

Can somebody expalin that?